# Using strdup pointer as map key causes to a memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, strdup

We are having a 'Entry' class like below and std map with set of Entries. at the end we clean the map but valgrind shows possible leaks of the memory allocated via strdup function.

```
class Entry
{
public:
    char* m_key;
    t m_data;

    Entry(const char* key, t data)
    {
        m_key= strdup(key);
        m_data = data;
    }

    ~Entry()
    {
        free((void*)m_key);
        m_key = nullptr;
        delete m_data;
        m_data = nullptr
    }
};
```

Insert elements to the Map

```
std::map<const char*, Entry*, Predicate> map_Entries;

void Insert(const char* key, t data)
{
   Entry *pNewEntry = new Entry(key, data);
   map_Entries.insert(std::pair<const char*, Entry*>(pNewEntry->m_key, pNewEntry));
}
```

Clear element from the map

```
void Clear()
{
  typename std::map<const char*, Entry*, Predicate>::iterator it;
    for(it = map_Entries.begin(); it != map_Entries.end(); it++)
        delete (*it).second;

    map_Entries.clear();
}
```

Predicate is comparison operator like below.

```
struct Mapcasestr
{
  bool operator()(const char* s1, const char* s2) const { return strcasecmp(s1, s2) < 0; }
};
```

Valgrind issue

```
==5666==    at 0x4C29BC3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==5666==    by 0x8098AF9: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
 ==5666==    by 0x4E92B1: Entry::Entry(char const*, T*)
```

I am aware that using raw pointers as map keys is not a good practice and we have better options than strdup. But this is an old code base and I am trying to fix memory leaks there. What I want to know is why valgrind report possible leaks even though we free memory allocated via strdup function?

Comment: The memory leak can be anywhere in your code, what makes you believe that the leak occurs specifically in the shown parts of the code? A more interesting question would be whether `Clear()` makes demons fly out of everyone's noses by deleting the strings the map's keys point to, and the map references indirectly, before deleting the entire map.

Comment: When you use a pointer as the key in a map, it's the actual *pointer* which is the key, not what it might point to. That makes them very bad as Keys, and makes it harder to read and understand your code.

Comment: And generally, for any kind of string needs, use `std::string`. It will make your problem disappear. My recommendation is to always try and follow *the rule of zero*. Also I don't see the need to store pointers in the map data. Why do you do that?

Comment: Also a note about using the same pointer as both key and member of the class... It will lead to *undefined behavior* as you free the memory, while the map still have a pointer to that memory.

Comment: Finally about the Valgrind message and the shown code. Please try to always include a proper [mcve] in your question, and copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need the cast in `free((void*)m_key);`. `free(m_key);` is sufficient and doesn't raise red flags. Also, `m_key = nullptr;` and `m_data = nullptr;` in the destructor are pointless; the object is going away, so its fields are no longer accessible.